# Counting repeated characters in a string in Python

Tags: python

I want to count the number of times each character is repeated in a string. Is there any particular way to do it apart from comparing each character of the string from A-Z
and incrementing a counter?

**Update** (in reference to [Anthony's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991350/counting-repeated-characters-in-a-string-in-python/991372#991372)): Whatever you have suggested till now I have to write 26 times. Is there an easier way?

Comment: The following thread is also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992408/determining-letter-frequency-of-cipher-text-in-python

Answer (score 48, accepted):

My first idea was to do this:

```
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
check_string = "i am checking this string to see how many times each character appears"

for char in chars:
  count = check_string.count(char)
  if count > 1:
    print char, count
```

This is not a good idea, however!  This is going to scan the string 26 times, so you're going to potentially do 26 times more work than some of the other answers.  You really should do this:

```
count = {}
for s in check_string:
  if s in count:
    count[s] += 1
  else:
    count[s] = 1

for key in count:
  if count[key] > 1:
    print key, count[key]
```

This ensures that you only go through the string once, instead of 26 times.

**Also, Alex's answer is a great one - I was not familiar with the collections module.  I'll be using that in the future.  His answer is more concise than mine is and technically superior.  I recommend using his code over mine.**

Comment: Even though it's not your fault, that he chose the wrong answer, I imagine that it feels a bit awkward :-D

Comment: It does feel awkward!  Isn't there a moderator who could change it?  I tried to give Alex credit - his answer is truly better.

Comment: Unless you are supporting software that must run on Python 2.1 or earlier, you don't need to know that dict.has_key() exists (in 2.x, not in 3.x). For situations not covered by defaultdict where you want to check if a key is in (HINT!) a dictionary, use e.g. """key in adict""" instead of """adict.has_key(key)"""; looks better and (bonus!) runs faster (no attribute name lookup, no method call).

Answer (score 125):

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for c in thestring:
    d[c] += 1
```

A `collections.defaultdict` is like a `dict` (subclasses it, actually), but when an entry is sought and not found, instead of reporting it doesn't have it, it makes it and inserts it by calling the supplied 0-argument callable. Most popular are `defaultdict(int)`, for counting (or, equivalently, to make a multiset AKA bag data structure), and `defaultdict(list)`, which does away forever with the need to use `.setdefault(akey, []).append(avalue)` and similar awkward idioms.

So once you've done this `d` is a dict-like container mapping every character to the number of times it appears, and you can emit it any way you like, of course. For example, most-popular character first:

```
for c in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True):
  print '%s %6d' % (c, d[c])
```

Comment: +1 not sure why the other answer was chosen... maybe if you explain what defaultdict does?

Comment: I should write a bot that answers either "defaultdict" or "BeautifulSoup" to every Python question.

Comment: @Paolo, good idea, I'll edit to explain, tx. @Triptych, yeah, they _are_ two useful little things;-).

Comment: I get the following error message after running the code in OS/X with my data in a variable set as % thestring = "abc abc abc" % http://dpaste.com/55220/

Comment: @Masi, per that dpaste link, you forgot the closing double quote: that's why it says "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal". Nothing to do with this question & answer!-)

Comment: Love collections.defaultdict.

Answer (score 47):

## Grand Performance Comparison

<sup>*Scroll to the end for a **TL;DR graph***</sup>

Since I had "nothing better to do" (understand: I had just a lot of work), I decided to do
a little performance contest. I assembled the most sensible or interesting answers and did
some simple `timeit` in **CPython 3.5.1** on them. I tested them with only one string, which
is a typical input in my case:

```
>>> s = 'ZDXMZKMXFDKXZFKZ'
>>> len(s)
16
```

Be aware that results might vary for different inputs, be it different length of the string or
different number of distinct characters, or different average number of occurrences per character.

---

### Don't reinvent the wheel

Python has made it simple for us. The `collections.Counter` class does exactly what we want
and a lot more. Its usage is by far the simplest of all the methods mentioned here.

*taken from **@oefe**, nice find*

```
>>> timeit('Counter(s)', globals=locals())
8.208566107001388
```

`Counter` goes the extra mile, which is why it takes so long.

### ¿Dictionary, comprende?

Let's try using a simple `dict` instead. First, let's do it declaratively, using dict
comprehension.

*I came up with this myself...*

```
>>> timeit('{c: s.count(c) for c in s}', globals=locals())
4.551155784000002
```

This will go through `s` from beginning to end, and for each character it will count the number
of its occurrences in `s`. Since `s` contains duplicate characters, the above method searches
`s` several times for the same character. The result is naturally always the same. So let's count
the number of occurrences just once for each character.

*I came up with this myself, and so did **@IrshadBhat***

```
>>> timeit('{c: s.count(c) for c in set(s)}', globals=locals())
3.1484066140001232
```

Better. But we still have to search through the string to count the occurrences. One search for
*each* distinct character. That means we're going to read the string more than once. We can do
better than that! But for that, we have to get off our declarativist high horse and descend into
an imperative mindset.

### Exceptional code

AKA *Gotta catch 'em all!*

*inspired by **@anthony***

```
>>> timeit('''
... d = {}
... for c in s:
...   try:
...     d[c] += 1
...   except KeyError:
...     d[c] = 1
... ''', globals=locals())
3.7060273620008957
```

Well, it was worth a try. If you dig into the Python source (I can't say with certainty because
I have never really done that), you will probably find that when you do `except ExceptionType`,
Python has to check whether the exception raised is actually of `ExceptionType` or some other
type. Just for the heck of it, let's see how long will it take if we omit that check and catch
all exceptions.

*made by **@anthony***

```
>>> timeit('''
... d = {}
... for c in s:
...   try:
...     d[c] += 1
...   except:
...     d[c] = 1
... ''', globals=locals())
3.3506563019982423
```

It does save some time, so one might be tempted to use this as some sort of optimization. 
**Don't do that!** Or actually do. Do it now:

<sub>***INTERLUDE 1***</sub>

```
import time
while True:
  try:
    time.sleep(1)
  except:
    print("You're trapped in your own trap!")
```

You see? It catches `KeyboardInterrupt`, besides other things. In fact, it catches all the
exceptions there are. Including ones you might not have even heard about, like `SystemExit`.

<sub>***INTERLUDE 2***</sub>

```
import sys
try:
  print("Goodbye. I'm going to die soon.")
  sys.exit()
except:
  print('BACK FROM THE DEAD!!!')
```

Now back to counting letters and numbers and other characters.

### Playing catch-up

Exceptions aren't the way to go. You have to try hard to catch up with them, and when you finally
do, they just throw up on you and then raise their eyebrows like it's your fault. Luckily brave
fellows have paved our way so we can do away with exceptions, at least in this little exercise.

The `dict` class has a nice method – `get` – which allows us to retrieve an item from a
dictionary, just like `d[k]`. Except when the key `k` is not in the dictionary, it can return
a default value. Let's use that method instead of fiddling with exceptions.

*credit goes to **@Usman***

```
>>> timeit('''
... d = {}
... for c in s:
...   d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1
... ''', globals=locals())
3.2133633289995487
```

Almost as fast as the set-based dict comprehension. On larger inputs, this one would probably be
even faster.

### Use the right tool for the job

For at least mildly knowledgeable Python programmer, the first thing that comes to mind is
probably `defaultdict`. It does pretty much the same thing as the version above, except instead
of a value, you give it a value *factory*. That might cause some overhead, because the value has
to be "constructed" for each missing key individually. Let's see how it performs.

*hope **@AlexMartelli** won't crucify me for `from collections import defaultdict`*

```
>>> timeit('''
... dd = defaultdict(int)
... for c in s:
...   dd[c] += 1
... ''', globals=locals())
3.3430528169992613
```

Not that bad. I'd say the increase in execution time is a small tax to pay for the improved
readability. However, we also favor performance, and we will not stop here. Let's take it further
and prepopulate the dictionary with zeros. Then we won't have to check every time if the item
is already there.

*hats off to **@sqram***

```
>>> timeit('''
... d = dict.fromkeys(s, 0)
... for c in s:
...   d[c] += 1
... ''', globals=locals())
2.6081761489986093
```

That's good. Over three times as fast as `Counter`, yet still simple enough. Personally, this is
my favorite in case you don't want to add new characters later. And even if you do, you can
still do it. It's just less convenient than it would be in other versions:

```
d.update({ c: 0 for c in set(other_string) - d.keys() })
```

### Practicality beats purity *(except when it's not really practical)*

Now a bit different kind of counter. **@IdanK** has come up with something interesting. Instead
of using a hash table (a.k.a. dictionary a.k.a. `dict`), we can avoid the risk of hash collisions
and consequent overhead of their resolution. We can also avoid the overhead of hashing the key,
and the extra unoccupied table space. We can use a `list`. The ASCII values of characters will be
indices and their counts will be values. As @IdanK has pointed out, this list gives us constant
time access to a character's count. All we have to do is convert each character from `str` to
`int` using the built-in function `ord`. That will give us an index into the list, which we will
then use to increment the count of the character. So what we do is this: we initialize the list
with zeros, do the job, and then convert the list into a `dict`. This `dict` will only contain
those characters which have non-zero counts, in order to make it compliant with other versions.

*As a side note, this technique is used in a linear-time sorting algorithm known as
**count sort** or **counting sort**. It's very efficient, but the range of values being sorted
is limited, since each value has to have its own counter. To sort a sequence of 32-bit integers,
4.3 billion counters would be needed.*

```
>>> timeit('''
... counts = [0 for _ in range(256)]
... for c in s:
...   counts[ord(c)] += 1
... d = {chr(i): count for i,count in enumerate(counts) if count != 0}
... ''', globals=locals())
25.438595562001865
```

Ouch! Not cool! Let's try and see how long it takes when we omit building the dictionary.

```
>>> timeit('''
... counts = [0 for _ in range(256)]
... for c in s:
...   counts[ord(c)] += 1
... ''', globals=locals())
10.564866792999965
```

Still bad. But wait, what's `[0 for _ in range(256)]`? Can't we write it more simply? How about
`[0] * 256`? That's cleaner. But will it perform better?

```
>>> timeit('''
... counts = [0] * 256
... for c in s:
...   counts[ord(c)] += 1
... ''', globals=locals())
3.290163638001104
```

Considerably. Now let's put the dictionary back in.

```
>>> timeit('''
... counts = [0] * 256
... for c in s:
...   counts[ord(c)] += 1
... d = {chr(i): count for i,count in enumerate(counts) if count != 0}
... ''', globals=locals())
18.000623562998953
```

Almost six times slower. Why does it take so long? Because when we `enumerate(counts)`, we have
to check every one of the 256 counts and see if it's zero. But we already know which counts are
zero and which are not.

```
>>> timeit('''
... counts = [0] * 256
... for c in s:
...   counts[ord(c)] += 1
... d = {c: counts[ord(c)] for c in set(s)}
... ''', globals=locals())
5.826531438000529
```

It probably won't get much better than that, at least not for such a small input. Plus it's only
usable for 8-bit EASCII characters. О блять!

## And the winner is...

```
>>> timeit('''
... d = {}
... for c in s:
...   if c in d:
...     d[c] += 1
...   else:
...     d[c] = 1
... ''', globals=locals())
1.8509794599995075
```

Yep. Even if you have to check every time whether `c` is in `d`, for this input it's the fastest
way. No pre-population of `d` will make it faster (again, for *this input*). It's a lot more
verbose than `Counter` or `defaultdict`, but also more efficient.

---

## That's all folks

This little exercise teaches us a lesson: when optimizing, always measure performance, ideally
with your expected inputs. Optimize for the common case. Don't presume something is *actually*
more efficient just because its asymptotic complexity is lower. And last but not least, keep
readability in mind. Try to find a compromise between "computer-friendly" and "human-friendly".

---

#### UPDATE

I have been informed by **@MartijnPieters** of the function `collections._count_elements`
available in Python 3.

```
Help on built-in function _count_elements in module _collections:

_count_elements(...)
    _count_elements(mapping, iterable) -> None

    Count elements in the iterable, updating the mappping
```

This function is implemented in C, so it should be faster, but this extra performance comes
at a price. The price is incompatibility with Python 2 and possibly even future versions, since
we're using a private function.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

> [...] a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. `_spam`) should be treated as a non-public part
>   of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member).
>   It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice.

That said, if you still want to save those 620 nanoseconds per iteration:

```
>>> timeit('''
... d = {}
... _count_elements(d, s)
... ''', globals=locals())
1.229239897998923
```

---

## *UPDATE 2:* Large strings

I thought it might be a good idea to re-run the tests on some larger input, since a 16 character
string is such a small input that all the possible solutions were quite comparably fast
*(1,000 iterations in under 30 milliseconds)*.

I decided to use the [complete works of Shakespeare](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/6/6.006/s08/lecturenotes/files/t8.shakespeare.txt) as a testing corpus,
which turned out to be quite a challenge (since it's over 5MiB in size ). I just used the first
100,000 characters of it, and  I had to limit the number of iterations from 1,000,000 to 1,000.

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/6/6.006/s08/lecturenotes/files/t8.shakespeare.txt'
s = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(100_000)
```

**`collections.Counter` was really slow on a small input, but the tables have turned**

```
Counter(s)

=> 7.63926783799991
```

**Naïve *Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)* time dictionary comprehension simply doesn't work**

```
{c: s.count(c) for c in s}

=> 15347.603935000052s (tested on 10 iterations; adjusted for 1000)
```

**Smart *Θ(n)* time dictionary comprehension works fine**

```
{c: s.count(c) for c in set(s)}

=> 8.882608592999986
```

**Exceptions are clumsy and slow**

```
d = {}
for c in s:
  try:
    d[c] += 1
  except KeyError:
    d[c] = 1

=> 21.26615508399982
```

**Omitting the exception type check doesn't save time (since the exception is only thrown
a few times)**

```
d = {}
for c in s:
  try:
    d[c] += 1
  except:
    d[c] = 1

=> 21.943328911999743
```

**`dict.get` looks nice but runs slow**

```
d = {}
for c in s:
  d[c] = d.get(c, 0) + 1

=> 28.530086210000007
```

**`collections.defaultdict` isn't very fast either**

```
dd = defaultdict(int)
for c in s:
  dd[c] += 1

=> 19.43012963199999
```

**`dict.fromkeys` requires reading the (very long) string twice**

```
d = dict.fromkeys(s, 0)
for c in s:
  d[c] += 1

=> 22.70960557699999
```

**Using `list` instead of `dict` is neither nice nor fast**

```
counts = [0 for _ in range(256)]
for c in s:
  counts[ord(c)] += 1

d = {chr(i): count for i,count in enumerate(counts) if count != 0}

=> 26.535474792000002
```

**Leaving out the final conversion to `dict` doesn't help**

```
counts = [0 for _ in range(256)]
for c in s:
  counts[ord(c)] += 1

=> 26.27811567400005
```

**It doesn't matter how you construct the `list`, since it's not the bottleneck**

```
counts = [0] * 256
for c in s:
  counts[ord(c)] += 1

=> 25.863524940000048
```

```
counts = [0] * 256
for c in s:
  counts[ord(c)] += 1

d = {chr(i): count for i,count in enumerate(counts) if count != 0}

=> 26.416733378000004
```

**If you convert `list` to `dict` the "smart" way, it's even slower (since you iterate over
the string twice)**

```
counts = [0] * 256
for c in s:
  counts[ord(c)] += 1

d = {c: counts[ord(c)] for c in set(s)}

=> 29.492915620000076
```

**The `dict.__contains__` variant may be fast for small strings, but not so much for big ones**

```
d = {}
for c in s:
  if c in d:
    d[c] += 1
  else:
    d[c] = 1

=> 23.773295123000025
```

**`collections._count_elements` is about as fast as `collections.Counter` (which uses
`_count_elements` internally)**

```
d = {}
_count_elements(d, s)

=> 7.5814381919999505
```

#### *Final verdict:* Use `collections.Counter` unless you cannot or don't want to :)

---

### *Appendix:* NumPy

The `numpy` package provides a method [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) which accomplishes (almost)
precisely what we want.

The way this method works is very different from all the above methods:

- It first sorts a copy of the input using Quicksort, which is an ***O(n<sup>2</sup>)*** time
  operation in the worst case, albeit *O(n log n)* on average and *O(n)* in the best case.
- Then it creates a "mask" array containing `True` at indices where a run of the same values
  begins, viz. at indices where the value differs from the previous value. Repeated values produce
  `False` in the mask. Example: `[5,5,5,8,9,9]` produces a mask
  `[True, False, False, True, True, False]`.
- This mask is then used to extract the unique values from the sorted input ‒ `unique_chars` in
  the code below. In our example, they would be `[5, 8, 9]`.
- Positions of the `True` values in the mask are taken into an array, and the length of the input
  is appended at the end of this array. For the above example, this array would be `[0, 3, 4, 6]`.
- For this array, differences between its elements are calculated, eg. `[3, 1, 2]`. These are the
  respective counts of the elements in the sorted array ‒ `char_counts` in the code below.
- Finally, we create a dictionary by zipping `unique_chars` and `char_counts`:
  `{5: 3, 8: 1, 9: 2}`.

```
import numpy as np

def count_chars(s):
  # The following statement needs to be changed for different input types.
  # Our input `s` is actually of type `bytes`, so we use `np.frombuffer`.
  # For inputs of type `str`, change `np.frombuffer` to `np.fromstring`
  #  or transform the input into a `bytes` instance.
  arr = np.frombuffer(s, dtype=np.uint8)

  unique_chars, char_counts = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)

  return dict(zip(unique_chars, char_counts))
```

---

For the test input (first 100,000 characters of the [complete works of Shakespeare](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/6/6.006/s08/lecturenotes/files/t8.shakespeare.txt)), this method performs better than any other tested here. But note that on
a different input, this approach might yield worse performance than the other methods.
Pre-sortedness of the input and number of repetitions per element are important factors affecting
the performance.

```
count_chars(s)

=> 2.960809530000006
```

If you are thinking about using this method because it's over twice as fast as
`collections.Counter`, consider this:

- `collections.Counter` has linear time complexity. `numpy.unique` is linear *at best*, quadratic
  at worst.
- The speedup is not really that significant ‒ you save ~3.5 milliseconds per iteration
  on an input of length 100,000.
- Using `numpy.unique` obviously requires `numpy`.

That considered, it seems reasonable to use `Counter` unless you need to be really fast. And in
that case, you better know what you're doing or else you'll end up being slower with `numpy` than
without it.

---

### *Appendix 2:* A somewhat useful plot

I ran the 13 different methods above on prefixes of the [complete works of Shakespeare](https://ocw.mit.edu/ans7870/6/6.006/s08/lecturenotes/files/t8.shakespeare.txt) and made an interactive plot. Note that in the plot, both prefixes and durations are displayed in logarithmic scale (the used prefixes are of exponentially increasing length). Click on the items in the legend to show/hide them in the plot.

[image: Interactive plot (click!)]

<sup>Click to open!</sup>

Comment: IMHO, this should be the accepted answer. Brilliant!

Answer (score 46):

Python 2.7+ includes the [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class:

```
import collections
results = collections.Counter(the_string)
print(results)
```

Comment: But like sunqiang pointed out, `collections.Counter` is also in python 2.7, and can be added to earlier versions.

Comment: I actually prefer this to Alex's answer

Answer (score 14):

This is the shortest, most practical I can comeup with without importing extra modules.

```
text = "hello cruel world. This is a sample text"
d = dict.fromkeys(text, 0)
for c in text: d[c] += 1
```

print d['a'] would output 2

And it's also fast.

Answer (score 7):

If someone is looking for the simplest way without `collections` module. I guess this will be helpful:

```
>>> s = "asldaksldkalskdla"
>>> {i:s.count(i) for i in set(s)}
{'a': 4, 'd': 3, 'k': 3, 's': 3, 'l': 4}
```

or

```
>>> [(i,s.count(i)) for i in set(s)]
[('a', 4), ('k', 3), ('s', 3), ('l', 4), ('d', 3)]
```

Comment: A one line for is the best.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a [dict](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

input = "this is a string"

d = {}

for c in input:
    try:
        d[c] += 1
    except:
        d[c] = 1

for k in d.keys():
    print "%s: %d" % (k, d[k])
```

Comment: that means i have to write the statement 26 times so as to find out how many times a character from a to z has repeated ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary:

```
s = "asldaksldkalskdla"
dict = {}
for letter in s:
 if letter not in dict.keys():
  dict[letter] = 1
 else:
  dict[letter] += 1

print dict
```

Comment: O(N**2)! Use """if letter not in dict:""" Works from Python 2.2 onwards.

Comment: I love that when testing actual performance, this is in fact the best fully compatible implementation.  See @kyrill answer above.

Answer (score 2):

I can count the number of days I know Python on my two hands so forgive me if I answer something silly :)

Instead of using a dict, I thought why not use a list? I'm not sure how lists and dictionaries are implemented in Python so this would have to be measured to know what's faster.

If this was C++ I would just use a normal c-array/vector for constant time access (that would definitely be faster) but I don't know what the corresponding datatype is in Python (if there's one...):

```
count = [0 for i in range(26)]

for c in ''.join(s.lower().split()): # get rid of whitespaces and capital letters
    count[ord(c) - 97] += 1          # ord('a') == 97
```

It's also possible to make the list's size ord('z') and then get rid of the 97 subtraction everywhere, but if you optimize, why not all the way :)

EDIT:
A commenter suggested that the join/split is not worth the possible gain of using a list, so I thought why not get rid of it:

```
count = [0 for i in range(26)]

for c in s:
    if c.isalpha(): count[ord(c.lower()) - 97] += 1
```

Comment: The idea expressed in this code is basically sound.  The python list has constant time access, which is fine, but the presence of the join/split operation means more work is being done than really necessary.  You can dispense with this if you use a 256 element list, wasting a trifling amount of memory.

Comment: Hi Greg, I changed the code to get rid of the join/split. It still requires more work than using the straight forward dict approach though.

Answer (score 2):

```
dict = {}
for i in set(str):
    b = str.count(i, 0, len(str))
    dict[i] = b
print dict
```

If my string is:

```
str = "this is string!"
```

Above code will print:

```
{'!': 1, ' ': 2, 'g': 1, 'i': 3, 'h': 1, 'n': 1, 's': 3, 'r': 1, 't': 2}
```

Comment: There are many answers to this post already. You should be weary of posting such a simple answer without explanation when many other highly voted answers exist.

Comment: @Benjamin If you're willing to write polite, helpful answers like that, consider working the First Posts and Late Answers review queues.

Answer (score 2):

If it an issue of just counting the number of repeatition of a given character in a given string, try something like this.

> ```
> word = "babulibobablingo"
> letter = 'b'
>
> if letter in word:
>     print(word.count(letter))
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
inputString =  input("Enter a String:")
countedArray = {}

for char in inputString:
    if char in countedArray:  
        countedArray[char] += 1    
    else:
        countedArray[char] = 1
    
print(countedArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

this will show a dict of characters with occurrence count

```
str = 'aabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
mydict = {}
for char in str:
    mydict[char]=mydict.get(char,0)+1
 print mydict
```

Answer (score 1):

For counting a character in a string you have to use `YOUR_VARİABLE.count('WHAT_YOU_WANT_TO_COUNT')`.

If summarization is needed you have to use count() function.

```
variable = 'turkiye'
print(variable.count('u'))
```

output: 
    1

Answer (score 1):

'''    #TO find the repeated char in string can check with below simple python program.

```
   str1 = "aaaaabbaabbcc"
    k = list(str1)
    dict1 = {}
    for char in k:
        cnt = 0
        for i in range(len(k)):
            if char == k[i]:
               cnt=cnt+1
        dict1[char] = cnt 

output you will get is  :  {'a': 7, 'b': 4, 'c': 2}
print (dict1) '''
```

Comment: can try as below also ..but logic is same.name = 'aaaabbccaaddbb'
name1=[]
name1[:] =name
dict={}
for i in name:
    count=0
    for j in name1:
       if  i == j:
           count = count+1
    dict[i]=count
print (dict)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution..

```
my_list=[]
history=""
history_count=0
my_str="happppyyyy"


for letter in my_str:
    if letter in history:
        my_list.remove((history,history_count))
        history=letter
        history_count+=1

    else:
        history_count=0
        history_count+=1
        history=letter


my_list.append((history,history_count))    


print my_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'today is sunday i would like to relax'
numberOfDuplicatedChar = len(s) - len(set(s))
```

#no duplicated element in `set`.

Answer (score -1):

Below code worked for me without looking for any other Python libraries.

```
def count_repeated_letter(string1):
    list1=[]

    for letter in string1:
        if string1.count(letter)>=2:
            if letter not in list1:
                list1.append(letter)


    for item in list1:
        if item!= " ":
            print(item,string1.count(item))


count_repeated_letter('letter has 1 e and 2 e and 1 t and two t')
```

Output:

```
e 4
t 5
a 4
1 2
n 3
d 3
```

Comment: whats the 12 for?

Comment: counting blanks obviously!

Comment: There you go, if you don't want to count space :) Edited to ignore the space.