# Determining Letter Frequency Of Cipher Text

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to make a tool that finds the frequencies of letters in some type of cipher text. 
Lets suppose it is all lowercase a-z no numbers. The encoded message is in a txt file

I am trying to build a script to help in cracking of substitution or possibly transposition ciphers.

Code so far:

```
cipher = open('cipher.txt','U').read()
cipherfilter = cipher.lower()
cipherletters = list(cipherfilter)

alpha = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
occurrences = {} 
for letter in alpha:
    occurrences[letter] = cipherfilter.count(letter)
for letter in occurrences:
    print letter, occurrences[letter]
```

All it does so far is show how many times  a letter appears.
How would I print the frequency of all letters found in this file.

Comment: What is the question? Note that you are scanning cipherfilter 26 times!

Comment: "All it does so far is show how many times a letter appears.. How would I print the frequency of all letters found in this file."  What?  Frequency IS how many times a letter appears.  If it shows how many times a letter occurs, that's the frequency of each letter.  This appears to work.  What's your question?

Answer (score 17):

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for c in 'test':
    d[c] += 1

print d # defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'s': 1, 'e': 1, 't': 2})
```

From a file:

```
myfile = open('test.txt')
for line in myfile:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    for c in line:
        d[c] += 1
```

For the genius that is the [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) container, we must give thanks and praise. Otherwise we'd all be doing something silly like this:

```
s = "andnowforsomethingcompletelydifferent"
d = {}
for letter in s:
    if letter not in d:
        d[letter] = 1
    else:
        d[letter] += 1
```

Answer (score 11):

The modern way:

```
from collections import Counter

string = "ihavesometextbutidontmindsharing"
Counter(string)
#>>> Counter({'i': 4, 't': 4, 'e': 3, 'n': 3, 's': 2, 'h': 2, 'm': 2, 'o': 2, 'a': 2, 'd': 2, 'x': 1, 'r': 1, 'u': 1, 'b': 1, 'v': 1, 'g': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the [relative frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_frequency) of a letter c, you would have to divide number of occurrences of c by the length of the input.

For instance, taking Adam's example:

```
s = "andnowforsomethingcompletelydifferent"
n = len(s) # n = 37
```

and storing the absolute frequence of each letter in

```
dict[letter]
```

we obtain the relative frequencies by:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase # this is "a...z"
for c in ascii_lowercase:
    print c, dict[c]/float(n)
```

putting it all together, we get something like this:

```
# get input
s = "andnowforsomethingcompletelydifferent"
n = len(s) # n = 37

# get absolute frequencies of letters
import collections
dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
for c in s:
    dict[c] += 1

# print relative frequencies
from string import ascii_lowercase # this is "a...z"
for c in ascii_lowercase:
    print c, dict[c]/float(n)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name.