# Determing relative letter frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a function that takes a text file as input and returns a vector of size 26 with the frequency in percent of each character (a to z). This must be insensitive to case. All other letters (ex. å) and symbols should be ignored.

I've tried to use some of the answers from here, especially the answer from 'Jacob'. [Determining Letter Frequency Of Cipher Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992408/determining-letter-frequency-of-cipher-text)

This is my code so far:

```
def letterFrequency(filename):
    #f: the text file is converted to lowercase 
    f=filename.lower()
    #n: the sum of the letters in the text file
    n=float(len(f))
    import collections
    dic=collections.defaultdict(int)
    #the absolute frequencies
    for x in f:
        dic[x]+=1
    #the relative frequencies
    from string import ascii_lowercase
    for x in ascii_lowercase:
        return x,(dic[x]/n)*100
```

For example, if I try this:

```
print(letterFrequency('I have no idea'))
>>> ('a',14.285714)
```

Why does it not print all the relative values of the letters? also letters that are not in the string, like z in my example?

and how do I make my code print a vector of size 26?

EDIT: I have tried using Counter, but it prints ('a':14.2857) and the letters in a mixed order. I only need the relative frequency of the letters in ordered sequence!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x in ascii_lowercase:
    return x,(dic[x]/n)*100
```

The function is returned in the first iteration of the loop.

Instead, change it to return a list of tuples:

```
letters = []
for x in ascii_lowercase:
    letters.append((x,(dic[x]/n)*100))
return letters
```

Comment: thank you, this works.. but how do i remove the commas in the printed result? it prints [number, number, number], but I would really like to get [number number number] like an array

Comment: @Gliz Use `letters.append((dic[x]/n)*100)` and print it using `for e in letterFrequency('I have no idea'): print(e, end = ' ')`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your `for` loop:

```
for x in ascii_lowercase:
    return x,(dic[x]/n)*100
```

you return a tuple, so it will stop at the first iteration.

Use `yield` instead of `return`, and that will turn into a generator working as expected.

Also another way to make it work is to return a list comprehension:

```
return [x,(dic[x]/n)*100 for x in ascii_lowercase]
```

However, if your purpose is to count items, I recomment the use of the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) class:

```
def letterFrequency(txt):
    from collections import Counter
    from string import ascii_lowercase
    c=Counter(txt.lower())
    n=len(txt)/100.
    return [(x, c[x]/n) for x in ascii_lowercase]
```

As you see, `c=Counter(txt.lower())` makes all the job of iterating thru characters and keeping counts. And the counter behaves just like a `defaultdict`.

Note that `Counter` has also nice usefult methods, such as `c.most_common()`...

Answer (score 0):

Heyy! Here is your solution. I have used the script **question you asked as an example** :) (All i did was to make a string of it, called string)

```
string = ' your text '
    alpha_count = {}
    string = string.lower()
    for alpha in string:
        match = re.search("[a-z]", alpha)
        boolean = bool(match)
        if boolean:
            if alpha in alpha_count:
                alpha_count[alpha] += 1
            else:
                alpha_count[alpha] = 1
    print(alpha_count)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'i': 18,
 'n': 18,
 'e': 47,
 'd': 7,
 't': 32,
 'o': 18,
 'c': 13,
 'r': 21,
 'a': 19,
 'f': 10,
 'u': 8,
 'h': 12,
 'k': 1,
 's': 19,
 'x': 3,
 'l': 9,
 'p': 4,
 'v': 3,
 'z': 2,
 'w': 3,
 'q': 2,
 'y': 4,
 'm': 6,
 'b': 4,
 'g': 2,
 'j': 1}
```

In case if you want to have a sorted view, use this code to after executing the code given above.

```
alpha_items = alpha_count.items()
sorted_items = sorted(alpha_items)
print(sorted_items)
```

OUTCOME:

```
[('a', 19), ('b', 4), ('c', 13), ('d', 7), ('e', 47), ('f', 10), ('g', 2), ('h', 12), ('i', 18), ('j', 1), ('k', 1), ('l', 9), ('m', 6), ('n', 18), ('o', 18), ('p', 4), ('q', 2), ('r', 21), ('s', 19), ('t', 32), ('u', 8), ('v', 3), ('w', 3), ('x', 3), ('y', 4), ('z', 2)]
```

Thank You!!!

Comment: CAVEAT! Do not forget to use a backslash for apostrophes and quotation marks in your text.
For example if you have a words like  
Jacob's should be made Jacob\'s
"Jacob" should be made \"Jacob\"
Use backslash before using every such character