# Get the number of occurrences of each character

Tags: python, string

Given the string:

```
a='dqdwqfwqfggqwq'
```

How do I get the number of occurrences of each character?

Comment: Compact solution tend to produce more concise code

Comment: Concise code is good, but clarity is more important IMHO.

Comment: This has a bunch of other ways, defaultdict is a nice way of doing it without counter (2.5+) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991350/counting-repeated-characters-in-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not highly efficient, but it is one-line...

```
In [24]: a='dqdwqfwqfggqwq'

In [25]: dict((letter,a.count(letter)) for letter in set(a))
Out[25]: {'d': 2, 'f': 2, 'g': 2, 'q': 5, 'w': 3}
```

Comment: It's O(N * sigma) where sigma is number of unique letters; nice improvement

Comment: Code golf: `count=lambda s:dict((c,s.count(c)) for c in set(s))`

Comment: Better Code golf: count=lambda x:{t:x.count(t)for t in x}

Answer (score 19):

In 2.7 and 3.1 there's a tool called Counter:

```
>>> import collections
>>> results = collections.Counter("dqdwqfwqfggqwq")
>>> results
Counter({'q': 5, 'w': 3, 'g': 2, 'd': 2, 'f': 2})
```

[Docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). As pointed out in the comments it is not compatible with 2.6 or lower, but it's [backported](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/).

Comment: Jakob, if you want one line:

import collections; collections.Counter("dqdwqfwqfggqwq")

Ta-dah. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
listOfCharac={}
for s in a:
    if s in listOfCharac.keys():
        listOfCharac[s]+=1
    else:
        listOfCharac[s]=1
print (listOfCharac)
```

Output `{'d': 2, 'f': 2, 'g': 2, 'q': 5, 'w': 3}`

This method is efficient as well and is tested for python3.

Answer (score 0):

For each letter count the difference between string with that letter and without it, that way you can get it's number of occurences

```
a="fjfdsjmvcxklfmds3232dsfdsm"
dict(map(lambda letter:(letter,len(a)-len(a.replace(letter,''))),a))
```

Comment: Hey, no one is talking about efficiency, only about size :)

Comment: `a.count(letter)` is clearer than `len(a)-len(a.replace(letter,''))` if you want *that way you can get it's number of occurences*

Answer (score 0):

```
lettercounts = {}
for letter in a:
    lettercounts[letter] = lettercounts.get(letter,0)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

python code to check the occurrences of each character in the string:

```
word = input("enter any string = ")
for x in set(word):
    word.count(x)
    print(x,'= is', word.count(x))
```

Please try this code if any issue or improvements please comments.

Answer (score -2):

one line code for finding occurrence of each character in string.

for i in set(a):print('%s count is %d'%(i,a.count(i)))

Comment: This won't work since you will remove all duplicates before counting.