# How to convert dictionary into string

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to use the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192753/how-to-get-the-number-of-occurrences-of-each-character-using-python)

Instead of getting a dictionary, how can I get a string with the same output i.e. character followed by the number of occurrences

Example:d2m2e2s3

Comment: How do you want the string to be formatted?

Comment: Can you explain the input and output? Are you trying to make string from the dictionary `Out[25]: {'d': 2, 'f': 2, 'g': 2, 'q': 5, 'w': 3}
`

Comment: I want the output as d2f2g2q5w3

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To convert from the dict to the string in the format you want:

```
''.join('{}{}'.format(key, val) for key, val in adict.items())
```

if you want them alphabetically ordered by key:

```
''.join('{}{}'.format(key, val) for key, val in sorted(adict.items()))
```

Comment: I want the letters followed by each time it has occurred in the original string in order.

Comment: I tried python 2.6, ValueError: zero length field name in format. should be ''.join('{0}{1}'.format(key, val) for key, val in adict.items())

Comment: from python 3.6:   `''.join(f'{k}{v}' for k,v in my_dict.items())`

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

dt={'d': 2, 'f': 2, 'g': 2, 'q': 5, 'w': 3}
st=""
for key,val in dt.iteritems():
    st = st + key + str(val)

print st
```

output: `q5w3d2g2f2`

Or this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

dt={'d': 2, 'f': 2, 'g': 2, 'q': 5, 'w': 3}
dt=sorted(dt.iteritems())
st=""

for key,val in dt:
    st = st + key + str(val)

print st
```

output: `d2f2g2q5w3`

Example with `join`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

adict=dt={'d': 2, 'f': 2, 'g': 2, 'q': 5, 'w': 3}
' '.join('{0}{1}'.format(key, val) for key, val in sorted(adict.items()))
```

output: `'d2 f2 g2 q5 w3'`

Comment: It's not the best variant because list comprehension and string concatenation with `join` is faster

Comment: I want the letters followed by each time it has occurred in the original string in order

Comment: @San4ez, I have added the example with join too.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the dict solution, just use join to join them into a string:

`''.join([k+str(v) for k,v in result.iteritems()])`

You can replace the `''` with whatever separater (including none) you want between numbers

Comment: Output required is of type: d2m2e2s3

Comment: Okay, I modified my answer to include the key (i.e. the letter)

Comment: I want the letters followed by each time it has occurred in the original string in order

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> result = {'d': 2, 'f': 2, 'g': 2, 'q': 5, 'w': 3}
>>> ''.join('%s%d' % (k,v) for k,v in result.iteritems())
'q5w3d2g2f2'
```

or if you want them alphabetically...

```
>>> ''.join('%s%d' % (k,v) for k,v in sorted(result.iteritems()))
'd2f2g2q5w3'
```

or if you want them in increasing order of count...

```
>>> ''.join('%s%d' % (k,v) for k,v in sorted(result.iteritems(),key=lambda x:x[1]))
'd2g2f2w3q5'
```

Comment: I want the letters followed by each time it has occurred in the original string in order

Answer (score -1):

Another approach, avoiding the `%` interpolation (or `format()`) by using  `join()` only:

```
''.join(''.join((k, str(v))) for k,v in mydict.items())
```