# Python replace apostrophes in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I have a dictionary that has apostrophes for the value and key in every entry. For instance one entry would look like this:

```
{'lat': '38.683959', 'lon': '-90.265198', 'accuracy': '3'}
```

I need to get rid of these apostrophes so I can write them into SQL. The single quotes cause an error when I try to write them. What is the best way to get rid of all of the apostrophes?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Those apostrophes are there because its a string datatype.

Comment: Here is an answer. Can't mark as duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283725/how-to-create-a-python-dictionary-with-double-quotes-as-default-quote-format

Comment: Maybe you should show the code you are using to "write this into SQL". Your question is impossible to understand otherwise.

Comment: There are no apostrophes in the dictionary, it contains strings. When you print a dictionary, it puts quotes around the strings, but they're not really in there.

Comment: If you substitute into your prepared SQL query properly, the quotes shouldn't be put into it.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you want to encode the dict as a string and write to a single database column? If that's the case, you should be able to find an existing answer in SO pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for those who left useful feedback. What dmulter said pointed me in the right direction. I needed to convert the dictionary to a single string, and I found my solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472907/how-to-convert-dictionary-into-string

Answer (score 0):

Instead of leaving the question open, I wanted to answer it myself. One of the comments pointed me in the right direction that I needed to convert my dictionary to a string, and I found the solution to do that here:

[How to convert dictionary into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472907/how-to-convert-dictionary-into-string)