# Python: no. of occurences of each character in a string

Tags: python, string, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get the number of occurrences of each character using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192753/how-to-get-the-number-of-occurrences-of-each-character-using-python)

What is the best way to obtain the count of each character in a string and store it(I'm using a dictionary for this - can this choice make a big difference?)? A couple of ways that I thought of:

1.

```
for character in string:
    if character in characterCountsDict:
        characterCountsDict[character] += 1
    else:
        characterCountsDict[character] = 1
```

2.

```
character = 0
while character < 127:
    characterCountsDict[str(unichr(character))] = string.count(str(unichr(character))
    character += 1
```

I think the second method is better...
But is either of them good?
Is there a much better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in the most efficient way, it appears to be like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def count_chars(s):
    res = defaultdict(int)
    for char in s:
        res[char] += 1
    return res
```

Timings:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def test_counter(s):
    return Counter(s)

def test_get(s):
    res = {}
    for char in s:
        res[char] = res.get(char, 0) + 1
    return res

def test_in(s):
    res = {}
    for char in s:
        if char in res:
            res[char] += 1
        else:
            res[char] = 1
    return res

def test_defaultdict(s):
    res = defaultdict(int)
    for char in s:
        res[char] += 1
    return res


s = open('/usr/share/dict/words').read()
#eof

import timeit

test = lambda f: timeit.timeit(f + '(s)', setup, number=10)
setup = open(__file__).read().split("#eof")[0]
results = ['%.4f %s' % (test(f), f) for f in dir() if f.startswith('test_')]
print  '\n'.join(sorted(results))
```

Results:

```
0.8053 test_defaultdict
1.3628 test_in
1.6773 test_get
2.3877 test_counter
```

Comment: thank you :) definitely overkilled the answer :)

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: ;) that wondered me since long time... that's why.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe counter is performing so bad , since Counter is a dict

Comment: @wim: Counter uses `self.get` when updating itself, so its performance should be similar to `test_get`

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("asdasdff")
Counter({'a': 2, 's': 2, 'd': 2, 'f': 2})
```

Note that you can use `Counter` object like a dict.

Comment: oh wait....for a 20MB string it's actually taking more time(30 sec) than the method 2(12 sec) ?

Comment: You generate an input string something like `"asdasd" * 200`, right?

Comment: I read a file into a string: striing = file.read() (the file is about 20MB)

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Important question: what kind of data you are going to processed? Are you sure you only need the characters in the 0-127?

Comment: yes only characters in 0-127. The file I'm using for testing is the GPL duplicated a bunch of times.

Comment: In this case, your method is preferred. Just seems odd transformation `str()`

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/3812061 :)

Comment: Also, if you need only printable characters, just use `{c: string.count(c) for c in printable}` where `printable` is imported from module `string`