# Count and Return values of unique characters in a string

Tags: python, function, count

I'm having problems developing a function to count and return the values of characters in a string. Can't use set, list or dictionaries.
Example, the string is AAACCD, should return 3A 2C 1D.

```
def uniqueValues(string):
count = 0
for s in string:
    if s in "ABCDEFGHIJKL":
        count +=1
return count
print(uniqueValues("AAACCD"))
```

this will only show the output 6, which is the number of characters of the string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the number of occurrences of each character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192753/get-the-number-of-occurrences-of-each-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? You can use `str.count()`

```
def get_counts(s):
    out = ''
    for i in s:
        if i not in out:
            cnt = str(s.count(i))
            out+=(cnt+i+' ')

    return out.strip()

get_counts(s)
```

```
'3A 2C 1D'
```

Comment: you mean you cant use square brackets?

Comment: im not able to use list, set or dictionary for this. what you suggested was using an empty list and append it into that list.

Comment: ah ok, try second method'

Comment: Updated to use only string and not lists

Comment: thanks. just wanna ask, what does cnt = str(s.count(i)) actually does?

Comment: try running this, `s.count('A')` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**First take out the unique values from the string and than make a loop of it and count the each characters.**

#Python

```
from itertools import groupby

ab = ''.join(set("AAACCD"))

print(type(ab))

test_str = "AAACCD"

for i in ab:
    
    counter = test_str.count(i)

    print(counter, i)
```

Comment: @zeerock can you mark it for an up vote if you find it useful and working