# In Python how can I check how many times a digit appears in an input?

Tags: python, count, digits

For example let say

```
numbers=input("Enter numbers: ")
```

If someone inputs 11234458881

How can I make the output

1 occurs 3 times

2 occurs 1 time

3 occurs  1 time

4 occurs 2 times

And so on

Comment: Use the input like an array and see related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991350/counting-repeated-characters-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: The term for this is (a non-graphical) [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram), which should aid in *searches*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter("11234458881")
```

returns:

```
Counter({'1': 3, '8': 3, '4': 2, '3': 1, '2': 1, '5': 1})
```