# Number of the same characters in a row - python

Tags: python, string

I have a character (eg. "a") and I need to check a string (eg. "aaaabcd") for the number of occurances of "a" in a row (processing stops at "b" in this case and returned value is 4).

I have something like this:

```
def count_char(str_, ch_):
  count = 0
  for c in str_:
    if c == ch_:
      count += 1
    else:
      return count
```

So I was thinking... Is there a better/more pythonic/simplier way to do this?

Comment: So if the string is `baaaabcd`, it should return `0`?

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991350/counting-repeated-characters-in-a-string-in-python which was found with the Google search: "python count repeated characters in string".

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Yes, and if it is `aaabcdaaa` it should return `3`

Comment: @CharlesBurns Thanks for that, maybe I could use that too, but I do not think it is really duplicate as I need only number of occurances in a row and stop at different character no matter if the counted character is later found in the string again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `re.match` function will start looking in the beginning of the string

```
m = re.match(r'[%s]+' % ch_, str_)
return m.end() if m else 0
```

If you want the biggest number of chars in any part of the string:

```
max(len(x) for x in re.findall(r'[%s]+' % ch_, str_))
```

Comment: Thanks, re.match works just perfectly, I should have checked the re module documentation more carefully

Comment: You have to escape characters that are special in regexes.

Answer (score 4):

One option using [`itertools.takewhile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile),

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> str_ = 'aaaabcd'
>>> ch_ = 'a'
>>> sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda x: x == ch_, str_))
4
```

Comment: `ch` isn't a builtin so not sure why you give it a trailing underscore

Comment: @jamylak Right. I was just using OP's variable names.

Comment: @jamylak Habit for naming function parameters, but I see that according to PEP8 it is used to avoid conflicts with keywords

Comment: @NZT yeah that's why I was confused

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about the beginning of the string, you could use `lstrip` and compare lengths:

```
>>> x = "aaaabcd"
>>> len(x) - len(x.lstrip("a"))
4
```

Maybe not the most efficient way, but most likely the simplest.

Comment: processing doesn't stop at b in this case

Comment: @jamylak I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I'm not sure but `x.lstrip` would have to make a new string, possibly it still uses the memory of the old one, anyway +1

Comment: @lqc Thanks, probably the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

You could borrow from the `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import takewhile, groupby

def startcount1(s, c):
    group = takewhile(lambda x: x == c, s)
    return len(list(group))

def startcount2(s, c):
    key, group = next(groupby(s))
    return len(list(group)) if key == c else 0
```

After which

```
tests = ['aaaabcd', 'baaaabcd', 'abacadae', 'aaabcdaaa']
for test in tests:
    print test,
    for f in count_char, startcount1, startcount2:
        print f(test, 'a'),
    print
```

will produce

```
aaaabcd 4 4 4
baaaabcd 0 0 0
abacadae 1 1 1
aaabcdaaa 3 3 3
```

If you really cared you could use `sum(1 for _ in ..)` instead of `len(list(..))` to avoid materializing the list, but I find I care less about things like that in my old age. :^)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> sum(1 for c in takewhile('a'.__eq__, 'aaaabcd'))
4
```