# Pythonic way to tell if any character appears four times in a row

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Here's a piece of Python code that tells me if any character in a string occurs four times in a row:

```
str = "hello!!!!"
for i in range(0, len(str)-3):
   if str[i] == str[i+1] == str[i+2] == str[i+3]:
       print("yes")
```

What's a more Pythonic way of writing this, preferably with a regular expression?

I'm aware of this similar question but it asks about a specific character, not any character.

[Number of the same characters in a row - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885756/number-of-the-same-characters-in-a-row-python)

@JBernardo has an answer with regular expressions but it wants a particular character to match against.

I'm using Python 3, if it matters in your answer.

Comment: Please read up on regex (specifically, [capture groups](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/660/capture-groups#t=201607231539015815315)) before asking a question. This is basic stuff. And if you want to actually _understand_ the answers you get, you'll have to read up on regex _anyway_.

Comment: If you want to avoid `re`, try `len(set(my_str[i:i+4]) == 1`. This will give you the number of unique elements from `i` to `i+4`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regex you can use this to find a char that is repeated at least 4 times:

```
>>> s = 'hello!!!!'

>>> print re.findall(r'(.)\1{3}', s)
['!']
```

**Explanation:**

- `(.)` - match any character and capture it as group #1
- `\1{3}` - `\1` is back-reference of captured group #1. `\1{3}` matches 3 instances of the captured character, this making it 4 repeats.