# How to count frequencys in python?

Tags: python, frequency

I had a file called 'words.txt' which contains things such as. `#+=%£%=` and i need to go through and count each symbol without allowing any duplicates and then print my answer. for example it should look like this when printed:

```
# : 1
+ : 1
= : 2
% : 2
£ : 1
```

I know I need to use a for loop in this and that I need to use a set so It doesnt't allow any duplicates but how would I do it? Thanl you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting repeated characters in a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991350/counting-repeated-characters-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Do you have a list of all the symbols that could be found in the file?  Or is it all just random symbols in the file?

Answer (score 4):

A `set` isn't so useful here as it doesn't have a place to store the counts

```
from collections import Counter
with open("words.txt") as fin:
    c = Counter(fin.read())

for item in c.items():
    print("{} : {}".format(*item))
```

Comment: Why don't you let him find a soltion as it is clearly an exercise?

Answer (score 1):

Use python dictionary:

```
symbols = {}

for c in string:
  if c not in symbols:
    symbols[c] = 0
  symbols[c] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up dictionary.

Don't want to post more as it would only spoil the exercise.