# Python: how to optimize

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Suppose I am given a string of `len` n, for every substring whose first and last characters are same I should add 1 to `fx` and print the final `fx`.

ex for `"ababaca" , f("a")=1 , f("aba")=1 , f("abaca")=1`, but `f("ab")=0`

```
n = int(raw_input())
string = list(raw_input())
f = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n,i,-1):
        temp = string[i:j]
        if temp[0]==temp[-1]:
            f+=1
print f
```

Is there any way I can optimize my code for large strings as I am getting time out for many test cases.

Comment: Wouldn't `abaca` give you *3*, not 1? `aba`, `aca` and `abaca` are all substrings with matching first and last character.

Comment: And even `a` should give 4, `aba` should give 2...etc?

Comment: @MartijnPieters ya, they should give 3.

Comment: @ankitbiradar: but if `a` is 1, then `aba` gives 3 (the substrings `aba`, `a`, and `b` all qualify if strings of length one count), and `abaca` would be 6 (3 unique single characters plus the 3 substrings I already identified).

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور: not sure how you got 4 from `a`.

Comment: strings with length 1 are countable, nop?

Comment: In "aba" you have 4 matches: "a", "b", "a", "aba".  Do you want <bold>distinct<bold> substrings which are also palindromes?

Comment: @KennyOstrom not distinct , yes "aba" will be 4

Comment: basically number of substrings with first and last character same and repetition of substrings allowed right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just count the occurrences of each letter. For example, if there are n 'a's, in the string there will be n*(n-1)/2 substrings starting and ending with 'a'. You can do same for every letter, the solution is linear.

Add `len(string)` to the obtained value for final answer.

Comment: Darn, I was going to say that, if his original problem turns out to match this. I am not clear yet on what he actually wants since the math doesn't work out with his examples.  Actually your math doesn't work either at first glance although that's so hard to judge.  It looks like you would fail on the first test case, f("a") == 1, because 1*0/2 = 0.  Just add len(input)?

Comment: Its perfect. What I want to know is how did you come up with that logic, whats the thought process

Comment: for f("aba") also how will this logic give ans 4? *b* count is one and *a* count is 2 i.e. (1*0/2) + (2*1/2) = 1.

Comment: Yep if substrings of length one are qualified just add length of the string to the answer that't it

Comment: Look at the use of defaultdict in this answer to handle the first part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991350/counting-repeated-characters-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: @ankrit, re: thought process.  First eliminate the irrelevant stuff like raw_input and print. They should not be in the function, which takes a string and returns a number.  But you asked for optimization, so the obvious place to start is eliminating the intermediate values.  You don't care what the substrings are, so don't look at them at all; just look for repeated characters.  From there it is simple combinatorics.