# How to take a list of words, and delete any words that have more than one of the same letters

Tags: python, list

Say I have list of 5 words

```
my_list = ['python', 'apple', 'always', 'sky', 'lie']
```

How can I use a function to scan each word individually and delete any word that has the same letter occur more than once?

So after the function runs, the list should only contain

```
my_list = ['python', 'sky', 'lie']
```

Comment: Cheers for the edit @gahan, was typing this up as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner:

```
result = [item for item in my_list if len(item) == len(set(item))]
```

- Use list comprehension to make a new list
- Use `set` to check if the length changes(which means there is duplicate)

You can write a function to make it more readable:

```
def is_unique_string(s):
    return len(s) == len(set(s))

result = [item for item in my_list if is_unique_string(s)]
```

There is already a discussion here: [Counting repeated characters in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991350/counting-repeated-characters-in-a-string-in-python).

Comment: This works because a set will only store each character once - thus if the length of the word is the same as the length of the set - each letter is unique.

Comment: @cal97g Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer

```
list = ['python', 'apple', 'always', 'sky', 'lie']
new_list = []
for string in list:
    if len(string) == len(set(string)):
        new_list.append(string)

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def has_duplicate(s):
    for x in xrange(len(s)-1):
       if s[x] in s[x+1:]:
         return true
    return false

l=["python", "apple", "always", "sky", "lie"]
y=[s for s in l if not has_duplicate(s)]
```

Check if the n_th character is in the string sliced at the n_th character. ie

"apple"

- checks "a" in "pple"
- checks "p" in "ple", match