# how can i get index of two of more duplicate characters in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to store actual index of Two or more duplicate characters in a list. For that i used index() but it returns the same index of all the duplicate characters.
Any other solution for this problem.

Comment: post the code that you tried.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post  how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - find char in string - can I get all indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122291/python-find-char-in-string-can-i-get-all-indexes)

Comment: why do you have both [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting repeated characters in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991350/counting-repeated-characters-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Title requests string, but body requests list. :-|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let our list and our desired element be defined as follows:

```
my_list = [1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3]
desired_element = 3
```

Then you can use a nice built-in of Python, [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
indexes = [index for index, element in enumerate(my_list) if element == desired_element]
print(indexes)
```

The output is, as expected `[1, 4, 5, 7]`.

---

Or, in a nicer format:

```
def indexes(my_list, desired_element):
    return [index for index, element in enumerate(my_list) if element == desired_element]
```

And then just call it using `indexes(list, element)`.

---

If you are looking for efficiency (I doubt you are):

```
def indexes2(my_list, desired_element):
    for index, element in enumerate(my_list):
        if element == desired_element:
            yield index
```

For large lists (as far as I have tested), this is 4-5 times faster. Note that this returns a generator, and in order to visualise the result, you must convert it to a list using `list(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas we can read this to a pd series and do some operations in one go.

```
import pandas as pd

l = ['a','b','c','a','b']

d = (pd.Series(l)[pd.Series(l).duplicated(keep=False)]
     .reset_index()
     .groupby(0)['index']
     .apply(list)
     .to_dict())

d
```

Returns:

```
{'a': [0, 3], 'b': [1, 4]}
```

Or this:

```
d = (pd.Series(l)
     .reset_index()
     .groupby(0)['index']
     .apply(lambda x: list(x) if len(list(x)) > 1 else None)
     .dropna()
     .to_dict())
```