# Coding a function in python wihch count the number of occurances

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am a beginner in python and I wish coding a function having a variable number of parameters. This function must count the number of occurance of each character existing in all input strings.
let's rename this function as carCompt.

For example :

```
carCompt("Sophia","Raphael","Alexandre")
```

the result should be:

```
{'A':5,
 'D':1,
 'E':3,
 'H':2,
 'L':1,
 'N':1,
 'O':1,
 'P':2,
 'R':2,
 'S':1,
 'X':1}
```

thank you for help!!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Unfortunately, as written, this is a "write code for me" question. And this isn't a free code-writing service. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Try using dictionary as your starting point.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991350/counting-repeated-characters-in-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the collections module to use the Counter function. Such as:

```
import collections

def carCompt(*args):
    return collections.Counter("".join(map(str.upper, args)))
```

This will return

```
{'A':5,
 'D':1,
 'E':3,
 'H':2,
 'L':1,
 'N':1,
 'O':1,
 'P':2,
 'R':2,
 'S':1,
 'X':1}
```

If you want it to be case sensitive then leave it like:

```
import collections

def carCompt(*args):
    return collections.Counter("".join(args))
```

which will return

```
{'a': 4, 'e': 3, 'p': 2, 'h': 2, 'l': 2, 'S': 1, 'o': 1, 'i': 1, 'R': 1, 'A': 1, 'x': 1, 'n': 1, 'd': 1, 'r': 1}
```

Also I suggest changing the function name from carCompt to car_compt as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @Rahul K P yes we should first : import collections