# How do I check if 3/5 values are the same without the help of an array?

Tags: python

Good day folks.I'm new to coding and currently trying to figure out if I have a set of 5 die. die1, die2, die3, die4, die5 and I want to check if 3/5 have the same value. Is it possible without the help of an array? 
:)

Comment: what is 3/5 here? Can you elaborate your question please?

Comment: Sure. You need a variable per possible dice value (as counters) and a lot of "if"s. Edit: Could even work without counters and a single, massive "if".

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation. I'm trying to check if at least 3 dice have the same values out of all 5. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Without array:

```
s = (die1==1)+(die2==1)+(die3==1)+(die4==1)+(die5==1)
if s >= 3:
    print('yes')
else:
    s = (die1==2)+(die2==2)+(die3==2)+(die4==2)+(die5==2)
    if s >= 3:
        print('yes')
    else:
        s = (die1==3)+(die2==3)+(die3==3)+(die4==3)+(die5==3)
        if s >= 3:
            print('yes')
        else:
            s = (die1==4)+(die2==4)+(die3==4)+(die4==4)+(die5==4)
            if s >= 3:
                print('yes')
            else:
                s = (die1==5)+(die2==5)+(die3==5)+(die4==5)+(die5==5)
                if s >= 3:
                    print('yes')
                else:
                    s = (die1==6)+(die2==6)+(die3==6)+(die4==6)+(die5==6)
                    if s >= 3:
                        print('yes')
                    else:
                        print('no')
```

Editing my post since I found a better solution:

```
dice = (10**die1 + 10**die2 + 10**die3 + 10**die4 + 10**die5) // 10

print(dice % 10 >= 3 or dice // 10 % 10 >= 3 or dice // 100 % 10 >= 3 or 
      dice // 1000 % 10 >= 3 or dice // 10000 % 10 >= 3 or dice // 100000 % 10 >= 3)
```

I know it would be faster to do a loop or explicit string / integer search for a digit >= 3, but in this case implicit array looping is possible :-)

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. Use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

d1 = 1
d2 = 3
d3 = 4
d4 = 3
d5 = 3

counter = Counter([d1, d2, d3, d4, d5])
roll, count = counter.most_common()[0]

if count >= 3:
    print('At least 3 out of 5 values are the same.')
```

Strictly speaking, this does make use of a `list` (which I think is what you mean; an array is something else entirely), so it depends on what exactly your restriction means. You could always change it to a `tuple`...

Comment: Thanks, your code is really good, but I'm trying to avoid using [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5].

Comment: @Mark any reason in particular? What about `(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5)`?

Answer (score 0):

Quick update. Thanks for all the fast answer folks. Fount my answer in another forum:
[Counting repeated characters in a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991350/counting-repeated-characters-in-a-string-in-python)
Here's how I did mine:
 diceValues = str(die1), str(die2), str(die3), str(die4), str(die5)
print(diceValues)

for item in diceValues:
  count = diceValues.count(item)
print(count)

Comment: That uses a `tuple`. Why is a `tuple` okay, but not a `list`?

Comment: I'm just practicing stuff. Super new to coding and I want to learn as much as I can :) , gotta google tuple now

Comment: A `tuple` is exactly the same as a `list` except that you can't change what's in it.