# python: how to check if string has the same characters / the probability of repeating them is the same

Tags: python

How to check if a given string has the same characters or their probability is the same, which gives me True?

For example, if there is
`string = "aaaa"` the result is True
and:

```
string = "aabb" True
string = "aabbcc" True
p = "1122" True
p = "aaaaBBBB9999$$$$" True
```

but:

```
string = "korara" False
p = "33211" False
```

For `"aaa"` I can use `(len (set ("aaa")) == 1)`, but I don't know about the others.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991350/counting-repeated-characters-in-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try ?

```py
from collections import Counter

def check(v):
    return len(set(Counter(v).values())) <= 1

assert check("aabb")
assert check("aabbcc")
assert check("1122")
assert check("aaaaBBBB9999$$$$")
assert check("")

assert not check("korara")
assert not check("33211")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collection which will create a dictionary and then you can check for each value if they are equal.

The following piece of code does that:

```
import collections

counter = dict(collections.Counter("aabbcc"))

expected_value = next(iter(counter.values()))
are_equal = all(value == expected_value for value in counter.values())

print("Result for aabbcc: ", are_equal)

counter = dict(collections.Counter("korara"))

expected_value = next(iter(counter.values()))
are_equal = all(value == expected_value for value in counter.values())

print("Result for korara: ", are_equal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your string in this function

```
def repeating_probability(s):
    sarr={}
    for i in s:
        if i in sarr.keys():
            sarr[i] += 1
        else:
            sarr[i] = 1
    if len(list(set(sarr.values()))) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score -2):

There's a length() function for strings though.

Comment: It's len(), but that doesn't help count any individual character